# Power BI - Rank Visual

Tags: powerbi

I have calculated ranking using this formula which has worked perfectly well.

I am trying to find a way to invert the rank to make 1 a bigger value than 6 in my visualization. Thought about multiplying by -1 but this gives me an obvious challenge with my data labels.

Any suggestions?

RANK = RANKX(FILTER('Rank','Rank'[Month]=EARLIER('Rank'[Month])),'Rank'[Count])

Answer (score 0):

If you want `RANKX` to return 6 which is currently 1, please try this

```
RANK = RANKX(FILTER('Rank','Rank'[Month]=EARLIER('Rank'[Month])),'Rank'[Count],,DESC)
```